# Modify Perl script to output new line every 20 words

Tags: perl, text-processing

I'm using an open-source perl script to create a text corpus based on the English language wikipedia dump.  The plain text has been extracted, but various punctuation marks and the like still need to be removed.  However, the output of this script essentially creates a 7.2GiB text file containing a single line.  Due to my needs, I want to alter the script such that it inserts a new line character every 20 words.

So far, I've tried this:

```
$wordCount=0;

while (<STDIN>) {
  $wordCount++;

  //text processing regex commands here


  # Remove ellipses 
  s/\.\.\./ /g;

  # Remove dashes surrounded by spaces (e.g. phrase - phrase)
  s/\s-+\s/ /g;

  # Remove dashes between words with no spaces (e.g. word--word)
  s/([A-Za-z0-9])\-\-([A-Za-z0-9])/$1 $2/g;

  # Remove dash at a word end (e.g. three- to five-year)
  s/(\w)-\s/$1 /g;

  # Remove some punctuation
  s/([\"\�,;:%�?�!()\[\]{}<>_\.])/ /g;

  # Remove trailing space
  s/ $//;

  # Remove double single-quotes 
  s/'' / /g;
  s/ ''/ /g;

  # Replace accented e with normal e for consistency with the CMU pronunciation dictionary
  s/�/e/g;

  # Remove single quotes used as quotation marks (e.g. some 'phrase in quotes')
  s/\s'([\w\s]+[\w])'\s/ $1 /g;

  # Remove double spaces
  s/  / /g;


  chomp($_);

  if ($wordCount == 20){
    print uc($_) . "\n";
    $wordCount=0;
  }

  print uc($_) . " ";
}

print "\n";
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, as the raw output has only newlines scattered around arbitrarily.  I'd like to have the text formatted so it will fit on a typical 1200px wide monitor without word wrapping.

A sample input text from the file is

> The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Politics. Proponents of anarchism
>   (known as "anarchists") advocate stateless societies as the only moral
>   form of social organization. There are many types and traditions of
>   anarchism, not all of which are mutually exclusive. Anarchism as a
>   social movement has regularly endured fluctuations in popularity. The
>   term anarchism derives from the Greek ἄναρχος, anarchos, meaning
>   "without rulers",  its use as a synonym is still common outside the
>   United States. The earliest anarchist themes can be found in the 6th
>   century BC, among the works of Taoist philosopher Laozi,  and in later
>   centuries by Zhuangzi and Bao Jingyan. The term "anarchist" first
>   entered the English language in 1642, during the English Civil War, as
>   a term of abuse, used by Royalists against their Roundhead opponents.
>   By the time of the French Revolution some, such as the Enragés, began
>   to use the term positively,  in opposition to Jacobin centralisation
>   of power, seeing "revolutionary  government" as oxymoronic. By the
>   turn of the 19th century, the English word "anarchism" had lost its
>   initial negative connotation. Modern anarchism sprang from the secular
>   or religious thought of the Enlightenment, particularly Jean-Jacques
>   Rousseau's arguments for the moral centrality of freedom. Anarchism",
>   Encarta Online Encyclopedia 2006 (UK version). From this climate
>   William Godwin developed what many consider the first expression of
>   modern anarchist thought. Godwin was, according to Peter Kropotkin,
>   "the first to formulate the political and economical conceptions of
>   anarchism, even though he did not give that name to the idea s
>   developed in his work", while Godwin attached his anarchist ideas to
>   an early Edmund Burke. The anarcho-communist Joseph Déjacque was the
>   first person to describe himself as "libertarian". Unlike Proudhon, he
>   argued that, "it is not the product of his or her labor that the
>   worker has a right to, but to the satisfaction of his or her needs,
>   whatever may be t heir nature. Jesus is sometimes considered the first
>   anarchist in the Christian anarchist tradition. Georges Lechartier
>   wrote that "The true founder of anarchy was Jesus Christ and . In
>   Europe, harsh reaction followed the revolutions of 1848, during which
>   ten countries had experienced brief or long-term social upheaval as
>   groups carried out nationalis t uprisings. After most of these
>   attempts at systematic change ended in failure, conservative elements
>   took advantage of the divided groups of socialists, anarchists,
>   liberals, and na tionalists, to prevent further revolt. Blanquists,
>   Philadelphes, English trade unionists, socialists and social
>   democrats. Due to its links to active workers' movements, the
>   International became a significant organization. Karl Marx became a
>   leading figure in the International and a member of its General
>   Council. Proudhon's followers, the mutualists, opposed Marx's state
>   socialism, advocating political abstentionism and small property
>   holdings. In 1868, following their unsuccessful participation in the
>   League of Peace and Freedom (LPF), Russian revolutionary Mikhail
>   Bakunin and his collectivist anarchist associa tes joined the First
>   International (which had decided not to get involved with the LPF). At
>   first, the collectivists worked with the Marxists to push the First
>   International in a more revolutionary socialist direction.
>   Subsequently, the International became polarised into two camps, with
>   Marx and Bakunin as their respective figureheads. In 1872, the
>   conflict climaxed with a final split between the two groups at the
>   Hague Congress, where Bakunin and James Guillaume were expelled from
>   the International and  its headquarters were transferred to New York.
>   In response, the federalist sections formed their own International at
>   the St. Imier Congress, adopting a revolutionary anarchist program.
>   Black Rose Books 2005) ISBN 1-55164-251-4.

There's 7-something gigs worth of text in the file.  So using a list or other data structure might be a bit of overkill for these requirements.

What is needed in order to fit my requirements?

Comment: Can you show us the regex part. Looks like you are overwriting `$_` there.

Comment: What does the input to this script look like? You're incrementing `$wordCount` once per line, which only makes sense if you expect the input to contain one word per line.

Comment: @ruakh, check my edits for clarification to your comments.

Comment: @Jason: As I expected. `$wordCount` is misnamed: it's actually a `$lineCount`. You're adding a new-line after every twenty lines of input.

Comment: @ruakh, how can I adapt this code to fit my needs?  I'm tempted to write up a C executable to take care of this.

Comment: @Jason: See wespiserA's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set perl's input record separator to something frequent and useful, like a space:

```
$/ = ' ';
```

then loop over the input *word* by *word*:

```
while (<>) {
```

trim the *word*:

```
    s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

skip it if it was all space:

```
    $_ or next;
```

do any other transforms you need

and then add it to a stack, splitting any internal tabs or other space-like characters:

```
    push @words, split /\s+/;
```

next, check to see if you have 20 words, and if so, print them:

```
    print join(' ' => splice @words, 0, 20), "\n" while @words >= 20;
}
```

then print anything remaining:

```
print "@words\n" if @words;
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider using something like [Text::Wrap](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Text-Tabs+Wrap-2009.0305/lib/Text/Wrap.pm) or [Text::Autoformat](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Text-Autoformat-1.669002/lib/Text/Autoformat.pm) .

Answer (score 1):

```
open my $in, '<', $inFileName; 
open my $out, '>', $outFileName; 
my $wordcount = 0; 

while(defined( my $line = <$in> )){ 
  $line=~s/\n//g; #remove newline character
  #split the words into an array(could use '\W+' instead of ' ')
  my @words = split ' ', $line; 

  foreach my $word (@words){ 
    $wordCount++; 
    if ($wordCount == 20){ 
      $wordCount = 0; 
      print $out "\n"; 
    }
    else {
      print $out uc($word)." ";
    }
  } # end of foreach line in input 
} # end of file while loop 
close $in; 
close $out;
```

Comment: +1. I think you've changed more than you really should have -- there's no reason the script shouldn't use `STDIN` and `STDOUT` (with shell redirections or pipelines), and no reason to avoid `$_` and `chomp` -- but you fixed the main issue, which is that `$wordCount` was only incremented once per line.

Comment: There are lots of reasons to not use STDIN or STDOUT. Those are huge handicaps when you decide you want to change the sources and destinations.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about this problem, I'd suggest a brute force solution:
slurp the entire entry, 
split to an array based on " ", 
foreach the array and print "\n" after every 20 elements.

Comment: For smaller text files, this wouldn't be a problem. However, I don't have a 16GiB RAM machine handy to do this with...

Answer (score 0):

True to Perl, there are various ways to solve this, but one (perverse?!) way to do it is to read the file byte by byte instead of line by line, or slurping the whole thing in.  It's rather brute force-ish but it works.  Essentially you are trading memory use for disk usage.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

open(IN, "in.txt") or die;
my $rc = 1;
my $wc = 0;
my $new;
while ($rc != 0)
{
  # Read a byte - not safe for Unicode or other double-byte environments!
  $rc = read IN, $new, 1, 0;

  # We're only interested if the byte isn't punctuation (POSIX character class).
  if ($new !~ m/[[:punct:]]/)
  {
    # word boundary?
    if ($new =~ m/ /)
    {
      $wc++;
      if ($wc % 20 == 0)
      {
        print "\n";  # 20th word, time for a new line.
      }
    }
    print $new;
  }

  # move on to the next byte
  seek IN, 0, 1;
}

close(IN);
```